# Ubuntu 18.04 installation problem

Tags: boot, 18.04

I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04. At the end of the installation process, Ubuntu prompted me to restart the computer. When I clicked on restart, the PC froze. I also tried reinstalling Ubuntu, but even then I encountered the same problem.

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: Check if the **secure boot** is enabled or not in the BIOS menu. If it is enabled, disable it.

Comment: I disabled secure boot, but even then it ran into an error. It says: watchdog : bug :soft lockup cpu#3 stuck for 23s! .(something like this)

Comment: May be it has a relation with Nvidia graphic card.. Check this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nPprHes-K_Y)

Comment: Please edit your question by adding the a screenshot of the error you got. It is possible to post screenshots or code samples in AskUbuntu, so no need to post your screenshot in other websites and post the link here. Please post the image directly here.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use manual or automatic partitioning? Sometimes, manual-defined partition causes conflict with Secure Boot, because not all needed partitions to avoid conflicts are created.